# Bulk Excel Export in C#

Tags: c#, .net, export-to-excel, openxml

We have around 100K rows which we want to write to Excel. Data is coming in JSON format & we are using JSON.Net to parse the data and write to Excel.
For writing to Excel we are using Open XML.

We don't want to create a POCO for the JSON & hence using JToken to directly read from JSON and write to File.
We are not facing any issue when the number of columns are less but in case we have about 200 columns in the Excel there seems to be some performance issues.

Any suggestions how this problem can be addressed or other ways we can achieve the desired output.

Updated Code:

```
 using (SpreadsheetDocument Excelfile = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, true))
        {

            Worksheet worksheet;
            worksheet = Excelfile.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet;

            JToken JTokenObj = JObject.Parse(JsonResp);
            List<JToken> JTokenList = JTokenObj["jsonkey"].ToList<JToken>();
            SheetData sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

            foreach(var tokenObj in JTokenList)
            {
                Row row;
                row = new Row() { RowIndex = i };
                sheetData.Append(row);


                Cell newCell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellAddress };

                newCell.CellValue = new CellValue(tokenObj["attributeName"]);

                row.AppendChild(newCell);
            }
            Excelfile.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            Excelfile.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Did you already analyse what the bottle neck really is? Are you directly writing Open XML or are you using a component to do so? Your description of the process can be improved by adding more details about the single steps and were you saw the performance issue exactly.

Comment: Have updated the post with some code. Issue is the process gets stuck. and throwing an exception. Doing an analysis to get the exact exception but want to know if we are doing something fundamentally wrong out here.

Comment: Providing us detail information about the exception seems crucial.